# php mailer not showing errors but not sending emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a server with email service and im trying to send emails using phpmailer like this:

```
include('config/class_phpmailer.php');

$email = new PHPMailer();

$email->IsSMTP();
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'; // netcabo
$email->Port = 587; 
$email->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$email->Username = my_email@netcabo.pt;
$email->Password = my_password;
$email->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$email->From      = my_email@netcabo.pt;
$email->FromName  = 'my_name';
$email->Subject   = $subject;
$email->Body      = $message;

// Set the Atatchment
if($attach) {
    $email->AddAttachment($attach);
}
// set the emails to send the message
foreach($emails_to as $mail) {
    $email->addAddress($mail);
}
// send the email
if(!$email->Send()) {
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $email->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

This works perfectly on localhost but when i upload it into a server, it gives me an error saying: "Message was not sent
PHPMailer Error: SMTP connect() failed". So, i've tried changing the host, port, user and pass to my email account from that server and nothing happened. no error, no "message has been sent", nothing... The email wasnt sent either. just a blank page.

What am i doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: Search before you post. Follow the troubleshooting link in the error message - if there is no link, you're running a very old version of PHPMailer and need to update.

Comment: @eskimopest you did not include this class `class.smtp.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer and SMTP: Mail never shows up when sent from remote server, works fine on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756899/phpmailer-and-smtp-mail-never-shows-up-when-sent-from-remote-server-works-fine)

Comment: More to the point, base your code on the current examples provided with PHPMailer - you've used a long-obsolete one that won't work with recent versions.

Comment: Just after starting `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and then check by running your script.You will definitely got some error.

Comment: Try to add this `sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /path/to/your/config -t"
` in your `php.ini` or use `ini_set()`

Comment: after some changes, included the class.smtp, the email was sent but went to spam folder. Is there anything i can do to prevent that? I'll try to use the latest version on github but i dont think its that. I'll be back. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch an error you can do this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
// the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
```